# Redimensionar tamaño de una tabla al arrastrar con el cursor HTML

Tags: html, jquery, css

Quiero hacer que en usuario pueda agrandar el espacio que ocupa una tabla con click de arrastre. Algo así como pasa con el textarea que haciendole click en el extremo inferior se puede cambiar el tamaño.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```js
$(function() {
    var pressed = false;
    var start = undefined;
    var startX, startWidth;
    
    $("table th").mousedown(function(e) {
        start = $(this);
        pressed = true;
        startX = e.pageX;
        startWidth = $(this).width();
        $(start).addClass("resizing");
    });
    
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(pressed) {
            $(start).width(startWidth+(e.pageX-startX));
        }
    });
    
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if(pressed) {
            $(start).removeClass("resizing");
            pressed = false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

table th {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: green;
}

table th.resizing {
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hacer click y arrastrar. (Tamaño de columnas independiente.)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>th 1</th>
            <th>th 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td 1</td>
            <td>td 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Hacer click y arrastrar. (y qua las columnas tengan el mismo tamaño)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50%">th 1</th>
            <th width="50%">th 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>td 1</td>
            <td>td 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Esta solución fue extraída de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) en la respuesta de *user686605* en la pregunta [Resizable table columns with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156182/resizable-table-columns-with-jquery)
.

Para que las columnas tengan el mismo tamaño al cambiar la tabla se puede usar 
`width="50%"`.
Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Genial Gracias!!

Comment: Gracias por aportar pero no todas las preguntas han de responderse. Es mejor esperar a que el autor aclare qué ha intentado y qué error concreto tuvo. Resolverselo indirectamente valida este tipo de preguntas de baja calidad. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, lo lamento mucho, en la versión en ingles de esta pregunta tampoco colocaron algún intento, pero lo tomaré en cuenta

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Ten en cuenta, sin embargo, que este sitio no se parece al inglés no solo por el idioma. Aqui tenemos otras reglas y buscamos publicaciones más trabajadas. Un saludo